# Migrating Winsock console application to Windows subsystem - stack overflow

Tags: user-interface, compiler-errors, winsock

Hey there wonderful community!
I'm back with a question regarding a console server application I've made with winsock. It's finally reaching a stage where I would need a to add a GUI, and to do so, I need it to be using the Windows subsystem.
And so I started the migration.
Yet I'm hitting a stack overflow somewhere in my application, and for the life of me I can't figure out where. Perhaps it has to do with WIN being a non-blocking subsystem (hope I used my vocab correctly).

Anyway, I hope to enlist you all as helpers. Many thanks :)

```
    #undef UNICODE

    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <conio.h>

    // Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
    #pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

int minitialize();
int msend(char msendbuf[512]);
char* mrecv(bool show);
int mshutdown();
void GoToXY(int column, int line);
int scroll(void);
int printm(char *inp);
int printm(char *inp, DWORD color);
int mexit();
char *vir = "true";

int clientnumber=0;
int currentclient=0;
int lastclient=0;

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "10150"

struct _client
{
    bool con;
    sockaddr_in addr;   //Client info like ip address
    SOCKET cs;      //Client socket
    fd_set set;         //used to check if there is data in the socket
    std::string ip;
    std::string name;
    int i;              //any piece of additional info
} client[100];

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;


SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

DWORD WINAPI recvfunc(LPVOID randparam)
{
    while (true) {
        ClientSocket=client[currentclient].cs;
        if (mrecv(true)=="1") {
            client[currentclient].con=false;
            ClientSocket=client[lastclient].cs;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI headerfunc(LPVOID randparam)
{
    Sleep(500);
    while (true) {
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO SBInfo;
        HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, &SBInfo);
        int xx = SBInfo.dwCursorPosition.X;
        int yy = SBInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y;
        GoToXY(0,0);
        HANDLE hHeaderColor;
        hHeaderColor = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hHeaderColor, FOREGROUND_GREEN);
        std::cout<<"Server Started.  Current Client:"<<currentclient<<"  Clients connected: "<<clientnumber<<"        ("<<xx<<","<<yy<<")   "<<lastclient;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hHeaderColor, 0 |
                                FOREGROUND_RED |
                                FOREGROUND_GREEN |
                                FOREGROUND_BLUE);
        GoToXY(xx,yy);
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI sendfunc(LPVOID randparam)
{
    while (true) {
        char mmessage[512];
        std::cin.getline(mmessage, 512);
        if (strlen(mmessage)<2) {
            GoToXY(0,23);
            sendfunc("1");
        }
        char msendbuf[512]="Server> ";
        strcat(msendbuf,mmessage);
        if (msend(msendbuf)==1) {
            "Client must have disconnected. Please select a new client.";
            sendfunc("1");
        }
        if ((strncmp(msendbuf,"Server> /",9)) != 0) {
            printm(msendbuf,FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
        }
        GoToXY(0,23);
        for (int sp=0; sp<72; sp++) {
            std::cout<<" ";
        }
        GoToXY(0,23);
    }

    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    minitialize();
    HANDLE hRecvThread;
    HANDLE hSendThread;
    HANDLE hHeaderThread;
    DWORD dwRecvThreadId;
    DWORD dwSendThreadId;
    DWORD dwHeaderThreadId;
    hHeaderThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,headerfunc,"1",0,&dwHeaderThreadId);
    for (int mf=2; mf<25; mf++) {
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
    hSendThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,sendfunc,"1",0,&dwSendThreadId);

    // Accept a client socket
    for (int sock=1; sock<100; sock++) {
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        char sockprint[80];
        char sockchar[4];
        itoa(sock,sockchar,10);
        strcpy(sockprint,"Client ");
        strcat(sockprint,sockchar);
        strcat(sockprint," connected.");
        printm(sockprint);
        GoToXY(0,23);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printm("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        client[sock].cs=ClientSocket;
        client[sock].con=true;
        lastclient=clientnumber;
        clientnumber++;
        currentclient=clientnumber;
        hRecvThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,recvfunc,"1",0,&dwRecvThreadId);
    }


    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    mshutdown();
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}

int printm(char *inp, DWORD color) {
    HANDLE hOut;

    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut,
                            color);
    printm(inp);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, 0 |
                            FOREGROUND_RED |
                            FOREGROUND_GREEN |
                            FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    return 0;
}

int printm(char *inp) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO SBInfo;
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, &SBInfo);
    int xx = SBInfo.dwCursorPosition.X;
    int yy = SBInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y;
    GoToXY(0,22);
    std::cout<<inp<<"\n";
    scroll();
    GoToXY(xx,yy);
    return 1;
}

int msend(char msendbuf[512])   // Send a message
{
    if (strncmp(msendbuf,"Server> /exit",(strlen(msendbuf))) == 0) {
        mexit();
    }
    if (strncmp(msendbuf,"Server> /set_client",19) == 0) {
        int nm=atoi(&msendbuf[20]);
        currentclient=nm;
        ClientSocket=client[nm].cs;
        char sockchar[4];
        itoa(ClientSocket,sockchar,10);
        char sockprint[80];
        strcpy(sockprint,"New Socket: ");
        strcat(sockprint,sockchar);
        printm(sockprint);
        char clientprint[80];
        strcpy(clientprint,"Client: ");
        strcat(clientprint,&msendbuf[20]);
        printm(clientprint);
    }
    if (strncmp(msendbuf,"Server> /list_clients",(strlen(msendbuf))) == 0) {
        printm("Clients:",FOREGROUND_RED);
        for (int cm=1; cm < 100; cm++) {
            int cn=client[cm].cs;
            if (cn>0) {
                char cli[80];
                char cmchar[4];
                char cnchar[80];
                itoa(cn,cnchar,10);
                itoa(cm,cmchar,10);
                strcpy(cli,cmchar);
                strcat(cli,"  ");
                strcat(cli,cnchar);
                strcat(cli," ");
                strcat(cli,client[cm].ip.c_str());
                strcat(cli," ");
                strcat(cli,client[cm].name.c_str());
                printm(cli,FOREGROUND_RED);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (strncmp(msendbuf,"Server> /test",(strlen(msendbuf))) == 0) {
        char ipcon[500];
        *ipcon=(system("ipconfig"));
    }
    if (strncmp(msendbuf,"Server> /help",(strlen(msendbuf))) == 0) {
        printm("Type /help for help or:");
        printm("/set_client [client number]");
        printm("/list_clients");
    }
    int iResult3 = send( ClientSocket, msendbuf, 512, 0 );
    if (iResult3 == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printm("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
}

char* mrecv(bool show) //Recieve a message
{
    int iResult2 = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, 512, 0);
    if (iResult2 > 0) {
        if ((strncmp(recvbuf,"/",1)) != 0) {
            printm(recvbuf);
        }
        if (strncmp(recvbuf,"/ip",3) == 0) {
            client[clientnumber].ip=&recvbuf[4];
            char prin[80];
            strcpy(prin,"client[clientnumber].ip: ");
            strcat(prin,client[clientnumber].ip.c_str());
            printm(prin,FOREGROUND_BLUE);
        }
        if (strncmp(recvbuf,"/name",5) == 0) {
            client[clientnumber].name=&recvbuf[6];
            char prin2[80];
            strcpy(prin2,"client[clientnumber].name: ");
            strcat(prin2,client[clientnumber].name.c_str());
            printm(prin2,FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
        }
        if (strncmp(recvbuf,"/alert",5) == 0) {
            char *message=&recvbuf[7];
            char prin2[80];
            strcpy(prin2,client[clientnumber].name.c_str());
            strcat(prin2,": ");
            strcat(prin2, message);
            printm(prin2,FOREGROUND_RED);
        }
        if (strncmp(recvbuf,"Client> /alert",14) == 0) {
            char *message=&recvbuf[15];
            char prin2[80];
            strcpy(prin2,client[clientnumber].name.c_str());
            strcat(prin2,": ");
            strcat(prin2, message);
            printm(prin2,FOREGROUND_RED);
        }
    }
    else if (iResult2 == 0) {
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return "1";
    }
    else  {
        printm("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        printm("Client must have disconnected. Please select a new client.");
        return "1";
    }
    return recvbuf;
}

int minitialize()   //initialize the winsock server
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printm("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printm("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printm("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printm("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printm("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned long b=1;
    ioctlsocket(ClientSocket,FIONBIO,&b);


}

int mshutdown()     //shutdown the server
{
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printm("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

void GoToXY(int column, int line)
{
    // Create a COORD structure and fill in its members.
    // This specifies the new position of the cursor that we will set.
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = column;
    coord.Y = line;

    // Obtain a handle to the console screen buffer.
    // (You're just using the standard console, so you can use STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    // in conjunction with the GetStdHandle() to retrieve the handle.)
    // Note that because it is a standard handle, we don't need to close it.
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Finally, call the SetConsoleCursorPosition function.
    if (!SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coord))
    {
        // Uh-oh! The function call failed, so you need to handle the error.
        // You can call GetLastError() to get a more specific error code.
        // ...
        return;
    }
}

int scroll( void )
{
    HANDLE hStdout;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
    SMALL_RECT srctScrollRect, srctClipRect;
    CHAR_INFO chiFill;
    COORD coordDest;

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("GetStdHandle failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the screen buffer size.

    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &csbiInfo))
    {
        printf("GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // The scrolling rectangle

    srctScrollRect.Top = 1;
    srctScrollRect.Bottom = 22;
    srctScrollRect.Left = 0;
    srctScrollRect.Right = csbiInfo.dwSize.X - 1;

    // The destination for the scroll rectangle is one row up.

    coordDest.X = 0;
    coordDest.Y = 0;

    // The clipping rectangle

    srctClipRect.Top = 2;
    srctClipRect.Bottom = 22;
    srctClipRect.Left = 0;
    srctClipRect.Right = csbiInfo.dwSize.X - 1;

    // Fill the bottom row with blanks.

    chiFill.Attributes = FOREGROUND_RED;
    chiFill.Char.AsciiChar = (char)' ';

    // Scroll up one line.

    if(!ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer(
                hStdout,         // screen buffer handle
                &srctScrollRect, // scrolling rectangle
                &srctClipRect,   // clipping rectangle
                coordDest,       // top left destination cell
                &chiFill))       // fill character and color
    {
        printf("ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int mexit()
{
    msend("/server_closed");
    mshutdown();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Well, I see you're using the standard handles, which don't exist in a GUI application unless you call AllocConsole() yourself to create them, so that could well be your problem.  Other than this there aren't many differences between the console and GUI subsystems.

Comment: Forgot to say that I know there's quite a few things wrong with this, but I am aware of that and in the process of fixing the rest. Right now I'm just focusing on the stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the recursive calling in my "sendfunc" thread that tripped me up.
Specifically,

```
        if (msend(msendbuf)==1) {
            "Client must have disconnected. Please select a new client.";
            sendfunc("1");
        }
```

Because I continued to call "sendfunc" from itself, it caused the stack overflow.
So, for anyone else having these problems, watch for overkill recursive function calls.

I simply removed my sending function and I was good to go.